# Setting ServerTokens and ServerSignature in Apache

Tags: apache2, mysql, security, lamp, apache2.4

I have been following this tutorial closely

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-setup-a-dedicated-web-server-for-free/comment-page-8/#comments

I have installed Apache php & MySql

I have run the command `sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and I am trying to set the `“ServerTokens Full”` to `“ServerTokens Prod”` and `“ServerSignature On”` to `“ServerSignature Off”`, but I cannot seem to find these lines, What could I be doing wrong?

Im new to setting up dedicated servers so any guidance would be helpful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under recent Ubuntu versions, these Parameters can be found in `/etc/apache2/conf.d/security` instead of apache2.conf

The guide you are following is for a 4 year old version of Ubuntu, try to find a guide for *Ubuntu 12.04* (guessing that this is what you use).

Answer (score 9):

These configuration directives are now under:

> /etc/apache2/conf-available/security.conf

which is then symlinked by the `a2enconf` command to:

> /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf

Here are the associated Apache 2.4 docs:

- [ServerSignature](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serversignature)
- [ServerTokens](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servertokens)